# How to evaluate $\int\sin ^3 x\cos^3 x\:dx$ without a reduction formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

We have the integral $$\displaystyle\int \sin ^3 x \cos^3 x \:dx.$$ You can do this using the reduction formula, but I wonder if there's another (perhaps simpler) way to do this, like for example with a substitution?

Comment: Hint: $\sin^3 x \cos^3 x= \sin x(1 - \cos^2x)\cos^3 x$. The substitution $u = \cos x$ is then obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. You may write
$$
\sin^3 x \cos^3 x= \sin x(1 - \cos^2x)\cos^3 x=\sin x(\cos^3x - \cos^5x)
$$

Comment: I got the same answer using this.

Answer (score 3):

You may write $$\sin^3 x \cos^3 x= \frac{1}{8} \sin^3(2 x)= \frac{1}{32}(3 \sin 2x - \sin 6x)$$ that  is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple arguments subscripted shorthand:

$$ 8 s^3 c^3 = s_2^3 = \frac{3 s_2 - s_6 }{4}  $$

Normal notation:

$$ 8 \sin ^3 x  \cos ^3 x  = \sin ^3 2x = \dfrac {3 \sin 2x - \sin 6x }{4} $$

Integrate.

$$ \frac{1}{32}(3 \sin 2x - \sin 6x)$$ that  easily  integrates to

$$ \frac{1}{32}\big( \frac{-3 \cos 2x}{2} +\frac{ \cos 6x)}{6}\big) + C $$

Comment: Why not just use the extra characters for sine and cosine? What does $s_6$ mean?

Comment: I believe the subscript in these functions represents the multiple of $x$ that it is a function of although I have never seen this notation before

Comment: Multiple rgument in subscripted notation saves some typing.. Right?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sin ^3 x \cos^3 x d x 
= & \frac{1}{8} \int \sin ^3(2 x) d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{16} \int\left(1-\cos ^2 2x\right) d(\cos 2x) \\
=&\frac{\cos 2x}{48}\left(\cos ^2 2 x-3\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that by using:
$$(\cos(x)+j\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+j\sin(nx)$$
we can get:
$$\cos^3(x)-j\sin^3(x)$$
in terms of multiple angle formulas and lower power $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any trigonometric identities;

Substituting, $\ sinx=t$ and $ cosx\,dx=dt$

$$I=\int t^3(1-t^2)\,dt$$

$$I=\int t^3-t^5\,dt=\frac{t^4}{4}-\frac{t^6}{6}+C=\frac{sin^4x}{4}-\frac{sin^6x}{6}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

With $x=\arctan y$,

$$\int \sin^3x \cos^3x \, dx = \int\frac{y^3}{\left(y^2+1\right)^3} \, dy = \int \left(\frac y{\left(y^2+1\right)^2}-\frac y{\left(y^2+1\right)^3}\right) \, dy$$